# Install grunt using maven

Tags: maven, gruntjs

I am stuck with using maven for build and compile , but now introducing JavaScript building and automation has provided an interesting challenge, that can we use maven to install Grunt?

I have searched and found a lot of pom.xml [examples](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) ,[example](http://jhipster.github.io/development.html) running grunt and yoeman, etc but NONE for installing grunt

something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Install Grunt</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>grunt</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>install</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is a very late answer... by using the frontend maven plugin you "install" Grunt by putting it in package.json. Then, npm will download it for you. (Like in the example project)